# Checking if an Array element within an ArrayList contains a certain value

Tags: java, arrays, search, arraylist

I have this ArrayList - `ArrayList<Object[]> tree`...

I also have this Array - `Object[] move`...that has a size of 2.

In my program a **unique** 2D array is added to `move[0]` and an integer to `move[1]`. This array is then added to the ArrayList then the process is repeated so I have a list of 'moves'.

My problem is I am unsure how to find the arrays ('moves') within the ArrayList ('tree') that contain a certain value in the `move[1]` element **only** - as the `move[0]` element will be unique everytime.

I then want to make an array/list of all of the matches. For example, an array that contains all of the `move[0]` values that match up to the `move[1]` value of `3`. So I would be left with an array/list of 2D arrays that contain the required moves.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: What have tried ? Also, IMO, it will be better if you use an object, e.g. `Point`, instead of a 2d array (`Object[]`).

Comment: I recommend to change your design, instead of `ArrayList<Object[]>` use a `Map<String, Object[]>` and have a String constant `MOVES` to identify your 2D array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that what you need is a `key-value` data structure and you have chosen a rather odd way to implement it.
You should use either a `HashTable` if you can not use generics (you are in an old jdk for some reason) or use a `HashMap` using types to enforce type safety.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is just iterating through your `tree` object and building a new `ArrayList` with the found matches, but this will take time linear to the size of that `tree`.
If you're looking for speed, then you could maintain a `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Object[]>>`, where the keys are the integers you store in `move[1]`, and the value is a list of all the moves that have that key, so retrieving that list can be done in O(1)